# Python gets stuck when compiling

Tags: python

I have written a program that finds the smallest number that has every number from 1 to 20 as a multiple. My code in C++ works perfectly and finds the correct answer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    for( int i = 1; i < 300000000; i++ ){

        int check = 1;

        for( int j = 6; j <= 20; j++ ){

            if( i % j == 0 ){

                continue;

            } else {

                check = 0;
                break;

            }

        }

        if( check == 1 ){

            cout << i << endl;
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

However, the same program in Python - which works when finding the smallest number with all of 1 to 10 as multiples, but only if the range being searched is smaller (it works with 5000000) - simply will not compile. I goes on forever and I have to close the Terminal window.

```
for i in range( 1, 300000000 ):

    check = 1

    for j in range( 6, 21 ):
        if i % j == 0:
            continue
        else:
            check = 0
            break

    if check == 1:
        print i
        break
```

I am using Mac OS X Mavericks, if this is relevant.

**Edit:** I have tried switching to xrange, but this regrettably makes no difference.

**Edit2:** I left it on in the background - it did in fact just take about 14 minutes to run! I apologise, I should have done this in the first instance.

Comment: which version of python is this?

Comment: Especially ``for`` lops. They're *horrifically* slow. Use ``map``, *list comprehensions*, or tools like ``itertools`` to get significantly better performance. ``for`` should only be used for small iterations or when it's really the only option. And the ``xrange`` instead of ``range`` if you're in python 2.x as noted below.

Comment: I just did a bench of a simple ``for i in xrange(300000000): z = i%10`` and it took 20 seconds. Seriously, your program is just slow as hell as written. It's not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using Python 2.

Your problem is this:

```
range( 1, 300000000 )
```

You are building a list of 300000000 Python int objects. If we assume that ints in Python are 4-bytes (which is *tremendously* false), then you are allocating 300000000 × 4 = 1200000000 bytes = 1 GB.

You should replace it with the following:

```
xrange( 1, 300000000 )
```

The advantage of *xrange* is that it does not pre-allocate all the Python ints in advance. See the documentation of [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=xrange#xrange) for more information:

> The advantage of xrange() over range() is minimal [...] except when a very large range is used on a memory-starved machine [...]

With Python 3 this problem does no longer exist, because *range* has been removed and *xrange* has been renamed to *range*.

Note that this will solve any memory error you would encounter. This won't solve the problem of using a bad, slow algorithm. Python is not really speedy when dealing with numbers (but also other languages will perform slowly when using huge numbers).

Comment: This doesn't offer a solution to OP's problem.

Comment: It does if it's swapping out to disk, that would make the already slow python ``for`` loop even slower.

Comment: Your initial post only said *"I guess you are using Python 2. 
Your problem is this: range( 1, 300000000 ) You are building a list of 300000000 objects."* without any explanation of "What's wrong with Python 2?  How do I fix it?"  It's more well-explained now, although if it were me I'd also explain to OP why Python 2 v 3 matters in terms of the `range` function.

Comment: @Louis: ah, sorry. That's because I'm used to write answers incrementally and you were too fast. :)

Comment: Also ``int`` in python is a LOT bigger than 4 bytes. For example on OSX, ``sys.getsizeof(1) = 24``

Comment: @aruisdante: of course. What I wanted to say is that the list were too big even for a C array.

Comment: I was just attempting to head off the *'but I have 4GB of RAM'* response. A 1GB array would be large, but reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy responses! However, I can confirm that using xrange does not solve the problem.

Comment: @user3457004: well, at least your program now enters the loop. :)

Comment: @user3457004 As we've all told you, your approach is just really, really slow in python because of how you've designed it.

Comment: @aruisdante You were absolutely right! I thought there was a problem because C++ did it so quickly (hundreds of times faster).

Comment: @user3457004: even C++ will benefit from a different algorithm.

Comment: Indeed, the ``%`` operator is about the slowest mathematical operation there is. Doing it on large numbers is very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "compile"? How are you compiling Python code?

Try using [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange)

Comment: Many people seem to interchangeably use ``compile`` and ``execute``, sadly. Especially with interpreted languages.

Comment: Python _is_ compiled into bytecode, but OP clearly meant executed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is python 2 then you really need to change the `range` to `xrange`. `range` works by creating a list of the size specified which you are then iterating over item by item. However in this case you don't need the list itself, only the indexes which were contained in that list. So you should prefer `xrange` because it is a generator which means that it can iterate without creating a list in memory. This will save your program from having to create a really large list which will take up a lot of memory.

Note that in Python 3 `range` has the same behaviour that Python 2 `xrange` had.

```
for i in xrange( 1, 300000000 ):

    check = 1

    for j in xrange( 6, 21 ):
        if i % j == 0:
            continue
        else:
            check = 0
            break

    if check == 1:
        print i
        break
```

Also Python is an interpreted language, there is no compile step like there is in c++. What you are seeing is just a slow running time.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python program is not *wrong*, it is just very very slow because you are using a very bad algorithm.

Try this instead:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    return (a // gcd(a, b)) * b

res = 1
for i in range(2, 21):
    res = lcm(res, i)
print("Least common multiple of 1..20 is {}".format(res))
```

**Edit:** alternatively, you can use your algorithm (but make it about 400x faster) by realizing that 19 and 20 are relatively prime, therefore any solution must be a multiple of 19 * 20:

```
UPTO = 300000000
STEP = 19 * 20

for i in xrange(STEP, UPTO, STEP):
    if any(i % div for div in xrange(6, 19)):
        continue
    else:
        print("Solution: {}".format(i))
        break
```

which runs in about 0.94 s on my machine (vs. 0.0000249 s for the "good" algorithm == about 37,000 times faster again!).

Comment: I imagine we all assumed this was homework and didn't want to solve it for the OP. We already told them it was just slow.

Comment: @aruisdante: funny how "find a better algorithm" is repeatedly expressed as "use xrange". I would never have gotten the first from the second.

Comment: Using ``range`` on a low memory machine will cause swap, which will make a slow algorithm even slower. And if you notice my first comment to the OP's actual question was that his algorithm was slow. As an aside, just doing the allocation for ``range(300000000)`` takes nearly 20 seconds.

Comment: On my system, the OP's algorithm with *range* gets killed by the Linux OOM killer. With *xrange* it takes some time but it completes.

Comment: I tried to run it with the range and was worried I'd have to turn my little netbook off but the it got killed as well :(